# есть ли графический редактор html css?

Tags: html, css

Добрый день.Пишу веб приложение и ищу способ собрать ui(html css) без написания кода.Просто брать кнопку бросать на экран а позади чтоб генерился код.Неужели нету таких редакторов?

Comment: Все с которыми я лично сталкивался - дурацкие. Если приходится генерировать однотипный интерфейс много раз, то проще свой редактор написать для того чтобы набрасывать шаблон формы, а потом вручную корректировать. Если интерфейс не однотипный(используются всегда разные фреймворки, классы и т.д.) проще всегда вручную верстать. ИМХО